# scraping JSON with PHP

Tags: php, regex, json, web-scraping, scrape

I have done a lot of HTML scraping using Xpath. But now I have to scrape some JSON and don't know how to do that. The source I want to scrape is :

```
     {
            "ASIN" : "B00DR4LYHY",
            "FeatureName" : "price_feature_div",
            "Type" : "JSON",
            "Value" : 
            {
                "content" : 
                {"price_feature_div":"<div id=\"price\" class=\"a-section a-spacing-small\">\n<table class=\"a-lineitem\">\n    \n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t        \n\t\t                \n\t\t                            \n\t\t\t\t        \n\t\t                \n\t\t\t\t        \n\n\n\n\n\n\t\n<tr>\n    <td class=\"a-color-secondary a-size-base a-text-right a-nowrap\">Price:<\/td>\n    <td class=\"a-span12\">\n        <span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" 

class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price\">$37.60<\/span>\n        \n\n\n\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n        \n\n        <span id=\"ourprice_shippingmessage\">\t\n        \t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        \n        \n        \n\n\t    \n\t\t\n\t\t\n        \n            <span class=\"a-size-base a-color-base\">& <b>FREE Shipping<\/b><\/span>\n        \n        \n    \n\n\n\n        <\/span>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n\n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t            \n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\n    \n    \n\t\n<\/table>\n<\/div>"}

        }
    }
```

I get this code from:

```
$URL    = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/twister/ajaxv2?sid=188-4344403-7969026&ptd=OUTERWEAR&json=1&dpxAjaxFlag=1&sCac=1&isUDPFlag=1&twisterView=glance&ee=2&pgid=apparel_display_on_website&sr=1-3&nodeID=1036592&rid=0Q05FXGQJSA20X44DJVG&parentAsin=B00DR4LUQY&enPre=1&qid=1413775191&dStr=size_name%2Ccolor_name&auiAjax=1&storeID=apparel&psc=1&asinList=B00DR4LYHY&isFlushing=2&id=B00DR4LYHY&prefetchParam=0&mType=full&dpEnvironment=softlines';
```

What I need to get is the price ($37.60)

The code I'm using , as provided from Venkata is:

```
    $URL    = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/twister/ajaxv2?sid=188-4344403-7969026&ptd=OUTERWEAR&json=1&dpxAjaxFlag=1&sCac=1&isUDPFlag=1&twisterView=glance&ee=2&pgid=apparel_display_on_website&sr=1-3&nodeID=1036592&rid=0Q05FXGQJSA20X44DJVG&parentAsin=B00DR4LUQY&enPre=1&qid=1413775191&dStr=size_name%2Ccolor_name&auiAjax=1&storeID=apparel&psc=1&asinList=B00DR4LYHY&isFlushing=2&id=B00DR4LYHY&prefetchParam=0&mType=full&dpEnvironment=softlines';



    $page = file_get_contents($URL);
    $decoded = json_decode($page);

    $html = $decoded->Value->content->price_feature_div;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//frem dom method 
$elements = $dom->getElementById("priceblock_ourprice")->item(0);

//OR use extract it from xpath like below line
$priceNode = $xpath->query("//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    //$priceNode = $elements->item(0);
    $ourPrice = $priceNode;
    echo $ourPrice;
}
```

I think the best would be to use REGEX but what should the expression look like?

Comment: decode the json, extract the html, then feed it into dom as usual. And no, "best" would **NOT** be a regex.

Comment: @MarcB thanks but, can you explain how to do that?

Comment: http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: @MarcB the problem is I get a NULL array after the decoding :(

Comment: probably means the json's corrupted. json_last_error() should tell you a bit. more.

Answer (score 0):

**Extraction with PHP**

```
$json_string = '{"ASIN" : "B00DR4LYHY","FeatureName" : "price_feature_div","Type" : "JSON","Value" : {"content" : {"price_feature_div":"<div id=\"price\" class=\"a-section a-spacing-small\">\n<table class=\"a-lineitem\">\n    \n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t        \n\t\t                \n\t\t                            \n\t\t\t\t        \n\t\t                \n\t\t\t\t        \n\n\n\n\n\n\t\n<tr>\n    <td class=\"a-color-secondary a-size-base a-text-right a-nowrap\">Price:<\/td>\n    <td class=\"a-span12\">\n        <span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price\">$37.60<\/span>\n        \n\n\n\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n        \n\n        <span id=\"ourprice_shippingmessage\">\t\n        \t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        \n        \n        \n\n\t    \n\t\t\n\t\t\n        \n            <span class=\"a-size-base a-color-base\">& <b>FREE Shipping<\/b><\/span>\n        \n        \n    \n\n\n\n        <\/span>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n\n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t            \n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\n    \n    \n\t\n<\/table>\n<\/div>"}}}';

$decoded = json_decode($json_string);
$html = $decoded->Value->content->price_feature_div;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//frem dom method 
$elements = $dom->getElementById("priceblock_ourprice")->item(0);

//OR use extract it from xpath like below line
//$priceNode = $xpath->query("//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    $priceNode = $elements->item(0);
    $ourPrice = $priceNode;
    echo $ourPrice;
}
```

**Extraction in frontend *(I used jQuery in below solution)***

```
var jsonObj={
            "ASIN" : "B00DR4LYHY",
            "FeatureName" : "price_feature_div",
            "Type" : "JSON",
            "Value" : 
            {
                "content" : 
                {"price_feature_div":"<div id=\"price\" class=\"a-section a-spacing-small\">\n<table class=\"a-lineitem\">\n    \n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t        \n\t\t                \n\t\t                            \n\t\t\t\t        \n\t\t                \n\t\t\t\t        \n\n\n\n\n\n\t\n<tr>\n    <td class=\"a-color-secondary a-size-base a-text-right a-nowrap\">Price:<\/td>\n    <td class=\"a-span12\">\n        <span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price\">$37.60<\/span>\n        \n\n\n\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n\n        \n\n        <span id=\"ourprice_shippingmessage\">\t\n        \t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        \n        \n        \n\n\t    \n\t\t\n\t\t\n        \n            <span class=\"a-size-base a-color-base\">& <b>FREE Shipping<\/b><\/span>\n        \n        \n    \n\n\n\n        <\/span>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n\n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\t\t    \n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t            \n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\n    \n    \n\t\n<\/table>\n<\/div>"}

        }
    };
//using jQuery we extracted the price
var ourPrice = $(jsonObj.Value.content.price_feature_div).find("#priceblock_ourprice").text();

console.log(ourPrice);//"$37.60" is the value you can see in the browser-console
```

**Note:** I found syntax error at `"price_feature_div"` html value(in JSON value it should be in single line even it is HTML string). Noticed two line breaks in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but i can't get that output. what is that word ' val ' in ' val ourPrice = $(jsonObj ... ' i am in php and don't know what that means. and I am getting this source from a URL (i'll post the URL in my question) so what the exact code would be?

Comment: You're welcome. sorry thats typo its should be `var`, i corrected now please have a look. Curious to know that where are  you doing the extraction? Server side(back-end) or Client side(front-end)?

Comment: Updated answer with php code; Extraction done with DOM after json_decode (@MarcB already suggested)

Comment: the PHP code was what I needed but I still get that null variable when decoding the json. I will update and write the full code I am using in my question. Sorry for so much bother .

Answer (score 0):

> I think the best would be to use REGEX but what should the expression look like

**In some cases the regex works better than xpath (for limited size unstructured html text snippets).**

So you just get the raw data and sticking to the `$` you get what you want.

```
 $page = file_get_contents($URL);
 $pattern = '/\$[\d.]+/';
 $preg_match($page, $pattern, $matches);
 echo 'price = ', $matches[0];
```

See the [working demo](http://tarex.ru/testdir/test8.php).